# Convert "Text to outlines" in inDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, fonts, text

Ive got a sign i created in inDesign that i wish to export as a PDF using `file > PDF Presets > High Quality` to send to print shop.

When im in Illustrator and export a document to be sent to a print shop i `highlight the text object > right click > text to outlines` so that there is no issue of the font opening up on the print shops end when they open the PDF.

Is there a similar function / feature inside of inDesign ? Ive search the help menu but couldn't find it. Is it another workflow perhaps ?

Comment: Generally you dont nee dto outline fornts if you send pdf files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InDesign can outline type by either highlighting text with the `Text Tool` or selecting the `Text Frame` and then, just like in Illustrator, choosing `Type > Create Outlines` from the menu.

Although, PDFs *embed* fonts and there is generally no need to outline type for PDF output.

Comment: thanks, if a font was un embeddable due to a restriction / other, would i get an alert in the PDF export dialog window ?

Comment: Chances are any Font which restricts embedding will also **not** allow the conversion to outlines.